# How to re-link a linked image layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm used to using the Links window in Illustrator and InDesign. In Photoshop (CS6), I have some linked images, added using `File > Place`, which look like this on the Layers window:

[image]

So far, so good.

I want to swap them for different images, and/or force them to update - but I can't find a straightforward way to do this.

---

Just pasting the new image in is not ideal - they're part of a video animation updated in a different application, and creating new layers each time would create a lot of hassle. I'm looking to do the same sort of things you can do in Illustrator and InDesign with the `Relink` and `Update...` buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, in Photoshop-land, `Relink` is called `Replace contents` and is found through right-click on the layer:

[image]

I can't find any direct equivalent of the Illustrator/InDesign update button. Right now I'm just re-replacing every time the file changes, which is far from ideal.

It seems like Photoshop linked images only update if you edit them in Photoshop using "edit contents" - and "edit contents" loads the version stored in memory, not the file on the drive.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

here, try this, this works much better I think

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop CC2016 there is an `update all modified content` in the right click menu. I assume that this will update linked files modified outside of the `edit contents` process.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same drop down above "relink to file" will do exactly what the relink in Illustrator and InDesign do :)

Answer (score 0):

2018 update: To get linked smart objects in Photoshop CC, you have to cases:

- Already created objects:

  1. convert it;

[image]

2. relink it;

[image]

(you may set a hot key to faster these actions)

- Stored file to make it ***Smart*** and ***Linked*** object at once. Click `Place linked`. With this command you may upload a pile of files at once.

[image]

Uptodate Photoshop updates links on the fly.